# how can I make ts-loader not try to load .html files as typescript?

Tags: typescript, webpack, ts-loader, raw-loader

```
# component.ts
import template from './template.html'
```

results in:

> ```
>   TS2307: Cannot find module './template.html' or its corresponding type declarations.
> ```

ts-loader-default_e3b0c44298fc1c14

I tried putting `raw-loader` before and after `ts-loader`, and it made no difference.

```
loaders.unshift({
  test: /\.html$/,
  exclude: /node_modules/,
  use: 'raw-loader',
});
```

I also tried doing:

```
# component.ts
import template from '!!raw-loader!./template.html'
```

And that does not work either.

trace resolution shows:

```
======== Resolving module './heading.html' from 'app/javascript/components/heading/heading.component.ts'. ========
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'app/javascript/components/heading/heading.html', target file type 'TypeScript'.
File 'app/javascript/components/heading/heading.html.ts' does not exist.
File 'app/javascript/components/heading/heading.html.tsx' does not exist.
File 'app/javascript/components/heading/heading.html.d.ts' does not exist.
Directory 'app/javascript/components/heading/heading.html' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
Loading module as file / folder, candidate module location 'app/javascript/components/heading/heading.html', target file type 'JavaScript'.
File 'app/javascript/components/heading/heading.html.js' does not exist.
File 'app/javascript/components/heading/heading.html.jsx' does not exist.
Directory 'app/javascript/components/heading/heading.html' does not exist, skipping all lookups in it.
======== Module name './heading.html' was not resolved. ========
```

Why is it trying to load this as typescript or javascript?  How can I tell it to not do that?